# Change your "From Email" in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I receive forwarded emails from an email like info@companyname.com to my Gmail account; when I respond to these emails, I want they look as if they came from info@companyname.com instead of my Gmail account.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is entirely possible.

Here's a link to google's knowledgebase describing exactly what to do: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=22370

Comment: Wow that's pretty sweet, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not really a question for Stack Overflow, but have a look here:

http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/07/send-mail-from-another-address-without.html

It's a post on the official GMAIL blog outlining how to send via an external SMTP host.

Comment: @Andy: Ah ha ha ha I'd just noticed that mistake and was in there fixing. Thanks!